# error fórmula subtotales Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo la siguiente lista en la cual meter unos precios, la cual tiene una celda final que calcula el subtotal con la siguiente fórmula:

```
=SUBTOTALES(9;H10:H130)
```

Esta formula está metida en la siguiente celda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no da bien el precio ya que si yo sumo las celdas donde he introducido las cantidades

```
=SUMA(H10:H130)
```

El resultado es mayor que el que calcula la fórmula de subtotales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Dónde está el error de esta fórmula =SUBTOTALES(9;H10:H130)? Gracias.

Comment: No hay ningún motivo para que dé diferente. ¿En alguna celda usaste `=ALEATORIO()` o algún calculo en función de la fecha/hora? Si no, ¿podrías agregar a la pregunta algún ejemplo con valores que se puedan usar para reproducir el caso?

Comment: SUMA muestra siempre el mismo resultado, independientemente de si hay filtros activados o no. SUBTOTALES se ve afectado por el filtro, y solo te muestra la suma de las celdas visibles. ¿Tienes algún filtro aplicado en algún sitio?

Comment: No parecía haber nada raro, las celdas eran cantidades numéricas obtenidas mediante entrada manual u otras de una simple multiplicación, tampoco había ninguna celda con =ALEATORIO() y tampoco encontré ningún filtro raro, en cualquier caso ya lo entregué y quedaron en revisarlo todo. Gracias.